# Offering GDPR privacy policy for voice mail?

Tags: gdpr, recording, phonecall

Voice mail recordings can be "personal data" according to the GDPR (i.e., if the caller’s telephone number belongs to a natural person, and/or if the message contains personal data), so a privacy policy is required.

Article 13 says that

> the controller shall, **at the time when** personal data are obtained, provide the data subject with all of the following information […]

but reading the whole privacy policy on the voice mail announcement isn’t feasable, of course.

Is there any provision in the GDPR that would allow controllers, in such a context (voice mail announcement), to just *mention* how to get the privacy policy?